# Cannot resolve symbol 'mat-form-field', Can't bind to [(ngModel)] since it is not provided by any applicable directives

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material, webstorm

Hello so I have all the imports in my `appModule`, but the form components are still erroring and not working. Can someone advise?

app.module:

```jsx
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatTableModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatSortModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    ExportComponent
  ],
```

First error:

[image: first error]

Second error:

[image: second error]